# Prototype setting styles on an element

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Within my prototype class, I have a function called loginSuccess. With in this function I have this bit of code
`$$('#cartov .overlay-login-display').setStyle({display: 'none'});`

What I expected this to do was to hide the div. However, I get this exception: `Exception : TypeError: $$("#cartov .overlay-login-display").setStyle is not a function`

From everything that I have researched, this is the correct syntax. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [`each()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/enumerable/each)

```
$$('#cartov .overlay-login-display').each(function(ele) {
  ele.setStyle({display: 'none'})
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why I need to use the each if there is only 1 element in the dom?

Comment: $$() always returns an array so you need to iterate through it like an array even if there's only one value in the array.

Comment: Of course if setting display to none is all that's needed there are ways to optimise; like `.each(Element.hide)` or `.invoke('setStyle', {display: "none"})`